# can't seem to build a Qt project on eclipse (C++, Windows)

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, mingw

I have Qt installed + Qt Eclipse Integration + MinGW but I can't seem to find a way to build a new Qt GUI project.

I'm getting the following error:

Error launching builder (mingw32-make debug )
(Cannot run program "mingw32-make": Launching failed)

I've updated the Path variable and added all I can think about that can be related and nothing..

Path now is:

C:\PROGRAM FILES\THINKPAD\UTILITIES;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Downloaded Program Files;C:\Program Files\PC-Doctor for Windows\services;C:\Program Files\SMLNJ\bin\;C:\Program Files\Chez Scheme Version 7.4\bin\i3nt;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Qt\2009.03\qt\bin;C:\Qt\2009.03\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;

any ideas..??

Thanks,
C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing mingw, have you selected the checkbox to install mingw's make too?

You could have a look into c:\mingw\bin and see if there is a mingw32-make executable and you could try to launch mingw32-make from a windows console. Probably there is something wrong with your mingw installation.

Hope that helps,

Elrohir

Comment: I love u!!
Tnx so so much, I spent so much time on this thing..

everything works just fine now!
:)